# add a tooltip to an EXTJS Button

Tags: javascript, extjs, tooltip

I am trying to add a tooltip to my button, I tried differents ways, but nothing happen when i put the mouse under the button, this is a part of my code when i tried to add this tool tip 
this when i created the button called guestButton

```
 {
    xtype : 'button',
    id : 'guestButton',
    text : 'Guest User',
    handleMouseEvents: true,
    width : 80,
    x : 70,
    y : 150,
    formBind : false,                       
    handler : function() {
    this.up().LoginGuest();
    }
```

**and here when i tried to create the tooltip**

```
    var tooltips = [{
            target: 'guestButton',
            html: 'A very simple tooltip'
        }];
Ext.each(tooltips, function(config) {
        Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', config);
    });  

Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way of adding tooltips at render. 
@chrisuae is right , but it had not worked for me also. 
What worked was creating tooltip on render of element :

```
   {
        xtype : 'textareafield', 
        grow : true,
        fieldLabel : 'E-Mail-Adressess'
        itemId : 'email',
        afterLabelTextTpl : required,
        allowBlank : false,
        listeners : {
            render: function(c) {
            Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                target: c.getEl(),
                html: 'You can enter multiple emails here'
            });
           }    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to define a tooltip for a button in ExtJS using:

```
xtype : 'button',
id : 'guestButton',
text : 'Guest User',
tooltip: 'A very simple tooltip',
```

If your button is disabled, the tooltip will not show.  This is by design, but if you need to, you can override it with some CSS:

```
.x-item-disabled, .x-item-disabled * {
    pointer-events:all;
}
```

See fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tha).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, 
I simply deleted this line `handleMouseEvents: true,` magically it works